# Swift download with byte-range request

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, swift

I have allready implemented a download session, now what i wanna do is make it to download only a portion of that file. i know that its possible through the byte-range but im not sure how do i have to do that in swift. any help would be much appreciated. thanks.

```
@IBAction func btnStartDownload(sender: NSButton) {

    let downloadUrl = NSURL(string:"http://www.joomlaworks.net/images/demos/galleries/abstract/7.jpg")

    let sessionConfiguration:NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session:NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    let sessionDownloadTask:NSURLSessionDownloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(downloadUrl!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: data)

        var fileManager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        var paths:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        var documentsDirectory:NSString = paths[0] as NSString
        var databasePath:NSString = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingString("/\(response.suggestedFilename!)")

        fileManager.createFileAtPath(databasePath, contents: data , attributes: nil)
        NSLog("Database copied to\(databasePath)")


    })

    sessionDownloadTask.resume()

}
```